# Mac OS X use auto layout with view controller and allow window resize

Tags: macos, autolayout

I'm trying to add a view to fill the entire window in Mac OS X like so:

```
func viewDidLoad() {

    sparkView = NSView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 600,400))

    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sparkView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Left, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
        self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sparkView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
       self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sparkView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: sparkView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
       sparkView?.contentCompressionResistancePriorityForOrientation(NSLayoutConstraintOrientation(rawValue: 499)!)

}
```

Why does this constrain the window size? If i do this I can't make the window bigger. I want `sparkView` to always fill the window. For context, this is created in the view controller that comes inside the NSWindow in storyboard.

I tried not setting the frame of sparkView, but then the window just collapses and there is no height at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you create a view programmatically and want to use auto layout to position it, you need to turn its `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` property to false.