# resize view controllers as we resize window in mac application

Tags: swift, macos, xcode8

I already read so many answers for this question but still unable to resolve my issue. I am creating a mac application where I have a window and adding view controller to the same. When I resize any of the views while running other view controller doesn't resize on it own. I want to run my application on full screen mode and all other view controllers should run on full screen or similar to main window.

I already tried to run this but unable to achieve my result.

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()
    preferredContentSize = view.fittingSize
}
```

This even doesn't work
[Mac OS X use auto layout with view controller and allow window resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417245/mac-os-x-use-auto-layout-with-view-controller-and-allow-window-resize)

This my first view controller:

[image]

And if I resize it then after entering password successfully next view controller doesn't resize:

[image]

Comment: I don't really understand what your question is, especially if you say "When I resize an of the view while running other view controller doesn't resize on it own," but if you are talking about a window size and/or a window position, get the window controller involved.

Comment: @ElTomato I am new to Mac Application Dev so I have least information or knowledge about this.

Comment: @ElTomato do you have any solution

Comment: @ElTomato I already checked for answers and read about NSViewController and NSWindowController.